# Dell R910 Motherboard

Tags: dell-poweredge

Can i cut this handle with a small saw?
This is blocking my Zotac GPU.

[image: Dell R910 Motherboard]

Comment: instead of annoymously marking negative reviews, atleast tell me what criteria i didn't meet

Comment: One small slip with a saw and the motherboard is toast. This is a terrible idea. Unscrew it or unsolder it from the board.

Comment: that dosen't look like something that would be soldered - riveted, plastic fastened or screwed more likely. I think taking a saw to a server comes under "terrible IT practices" alongside juggling hard drives and using ram to stir your coffee...

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! By philosophy and design votes are anonymous and **neither voting [up](//serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) nor voting [down](//$SITEURL/help/privileges/vote-down) requires any mandatory explanation**. The tooltip that appears when your mouse pointer hoovers over the down button states: *"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. Also questions can attract a down vote when not [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681), not quite [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) or missing details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can cut it, or better if under the motherboard there is screw that hold that handle please just remove it the normal's way. It's a handle to help you remove/lift the board upside.

[image]

Comment: woukdn't it be screwed on? unscrewing it sounds like it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek ah, yes I agree ! but I can't validate under, I mostly checked the manual to make sure of the use of that handle. Even cutting it make more sense than sawing it for the residue that can produce, will edit

Comment: Thanks for the answer, exactly what i was looking for. I didn't want to take chances re-cabling all the components...so i ended up sawing it off :)

It was just a plastic in the end.  I used a small broken saw blade to surgically remove after putting loads and loads of tissue paper to cover the PCIe Slots (so that residue wouldn't get on it).

My zotac 1070 mini now sits perfectly giving me excellent framerates on Games